# How to show/hide certain div when i have multiple div with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had multiple div with class name **blueflip** i want to toggle this class's div content when the div **link_button** is clicked.

My Code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.blueflip').hide(); 
   $('.link_button').click(function() {
      $('.blueflip').toggle(400);
      return false;
   });
});
```

It works fine. But my problem is, my page has multiple **link_button** and **blueflip** div's all over the page. when i click any one of **link_button** all of the **blueflip** div's are toggling. But i need to toggle the corresponding child **blueflip** div only

Note : **The divs are dynamically generated from database.**

How to achieve that, Plz help. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Comment: whats the html structure of link_button and blueflip divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it, assuming that `.blueflip` is a child of `.link_button`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.blueflip').hide(); 
   $('.link_button').click(function() {
      $(this).find('.blueflip').toggle(400);
      return false;
   });
});
```

This works because of jQuery's [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method, which always searches for descendants of the selector indicated by the parent jQuery object.

If `.blueflip` nodes are not children of the corresponding `.link_button` nodes, you might need to introduce some trickery into your object IDs.  If everything has a unique ID (even if it's just an increment counter when the DIVs are generated), and you can correspond `.link_button` IDs to `.blueflip` IDs (e.g., `div#lb_001` corresponds to `div#bf_001`), then this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.blueflip').hide(); 
   $('.link_button').click(function() {
      $('#bf' + $(this).attr('id').substr(2)).toggle(400);
      return false;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If yo know the structure of page you would have to walk thru the dom tree, looking for the required div (maybe based on how many div's so far counted).

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/dombasics